# DataTables problem rendering from Ajax Json from Razor Pages .Net Get

Tags: json, ajax, .net-core, datatables, razor-pages

I have been trying to follow this example from DataTables (https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) and just can't seem to get the table data to load.  My ajax call is hitting the breakpoint in the .Net .cshtml.cs code-behind file and returning the json object.  But the data table just shows 'Loading'.  Would really appreciate if anyone has any clues as to what else I can try and I've attempted many different things based on other examples.  Thanks!

Here is my OnGet method, which the ajax call calls (verified through breakpoint hits):

```
public JsonResult OnGetAllCustomers()
{
    List<Customer> lstCustomers = new List<Customer>();
    lstCustomers = objCustomerDAL.GetAllCustomers();
    var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstCustomers);
    return new JsonResult("\"data\":" + output);
}
```

Here is my table definition:

```
        <div class="row">
            <table id="CustomersTable" class="display table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Company Name</th>
                        <th>Contact Name</th>
                        <th>Contact Title</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Here is the JsonResult in the Text Visualizer:

```
"data":[{"CustomerID":106,"CompanyName":"Clean Companyee","ContactName":"Mr Clean we","ContactTitle":"Washeree","Address":"111 Clean Steet","City":"Scrubee","State":"MT","ZipCode":"22222","Phone":"333-444-5555","Email":"clean@brush.com","DateCreated":"2024-01-30T11:29:15.997","UserIDCreated":4695,"DateLastModified":"2024-02-16T14:44:58.377","UserIDLastModified":4695},{"CustomerID":107,"CompanyName":"Bill's Paper Mill","ContactName":"Bill Sorenson","ContactTitle":"Owner","Address":"384 Running Brook Lane","City":"Dallas","State":"TX","ZipCode":"25415","Phone":"747-666-3333","Email":"Bill@Paper.com","DateCreated":"2024-01-18T14:42:10","UserIDCreated":4695,"DateLastModified":"2024-01-23T11:46:34.943","UserIDLastModified":4695},
{"CustomerID":108,"CompanyName":"The Addition Company","ContactName":"Joe Math","ContactTitle":"Mathemetician","Address":"333 Flower Lane","City":"Pittsburgh","State":"PA","ZipCode":"25412","Phone":"666-666-9999","Email":"joe@math.com","DateCreated":"2024-01-16T09:14:48.127","UserIDCreated":4695,"DateLastModified":"2024-01-16T09:14:48.127","UserIDLastModified":4695}, ... etc
```

And here is the JQuery, which is just like the example, but with the revised data columns and the Ajax using Get in .Net vs a text file.

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.0/js/dataTables.js"></script>

<script>
    // Formatting function for row details - modify as you need
    function format(d) {
        // `d` is the original data object for the row
        return (
            '<dl>' +
            '<dt>Phone: </dt>' +
            '<dd>' +
            d.phone +
            '</dd>' +
            '<dt>Email: </dt>' +
            '<dd>' +
            d.email +
            '</dd>' +
            '<dt>Extra info:</dt>' +
            '<dd>And any further details here (images etc)...</dd>' +
            '</dl>'
        );
    }

    let table = new DataTable('#CustomersTable', {
        ajax: {
            url: 'CustomersFlyout?handler=AllCustomers',
            dataSrc: 'data'
        },
        columns: [
            {
                className: 'dt-control',
                orderable: false,
                data: null,
                defaultContent: ''
            },
            { data: "companyname" },
            { data: "contactname" },
            { data: "contacttitle" },
            { data: "city" },
            { data: "state" }
        ],
        order: [[1, 'asc']]
    });

    table.on('click', 'td.dt-control', function (e) {
        let tr = e.target.closest('tr');
        let row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data())).show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

I know the Json is being returned but cannot get the data to populate to the table.

Comment: The JSON value `CompanyName` does not match the value you have told DataTables to look for: `companyname`. This fix (matching the JSON names) is necessary, but it may not be sufficient.

Comment: Some additional suggestions: You haven't shared any error messages generated by the browser (check the browser's console) - these may help. You haven't provided a [mre] - which could even be provided using a runnable [Stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). You can simulate your Ajax call using `setTimeout` as described in the link. Taking these extra steps would probably make it easier to provide a solution, rather than only providing hints towards a possible solution.

Comment: Hi Andrew.. thanks for the messages.  I have tried the names as the same CamelCase but that didn't do anything.  Many of the other posts out there say the names have to be lower case but will try again.  Also, there are no error messages thrown in console related to Datatables.  It just doesn't render.  Unfortunately I'm not at a level with JFiddle or Stack Overflow where I can produce a minimal reproducible example or I would.  What gets me is that I'm following the DataTables example word for word other than the Ajax call - but it's just passing this data to the columns that won't happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Json result is not valid Json. In the documentation link you provided you can check the `Ajax` tab to see how it should look like. Basically you are missing the braces at the start and the end.

[image]

Instead of serializing and concatenating the Json manually, the following code should give you the correct result:

```
public JsonResult OnGetAllCustomers()
{
    List<Customer> lstCustomers = new List<Customer>();
    lstCustomers = objCustomerDAL.GetAllCustomers();
    
    return new JsonResult(new
    {
        data = lstCustomers
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitris!! That was it! I did have to modify the customername column to be customerName etc., but used your method and it worked right away! Do much appreciate your help!  Marked the check box as solved!!